# Resolve symbolic name to version number from command line with Ivy/ant?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to resolve what version is being grabbed by ivy for a specific package from the command line?

I'm looking for something like, say

```
$ ant resolve com.internal.shared.pkg latest.release
```

which would then return, say, "1.1.18"

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no...

It is possible, but it will take a lot of elbow grease on your part. You have to write an Ant `<target>` for it in your `build.xml` file.

The target will use the [`<ivy:resolve>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/resolve.html) task in an **inline** mode. This means you give it the *organisation*, *module*, and *revision*, and Ivy will attempt to download it.

From there, you have a few options. I took a look at [`<ivy:report>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/report.html) since it seemed the easiest way to generate the report. However, it might be easier downloading it via the [`<ivy:retrieve>`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) and seeing what you downloaded.

Here's what my `<ivy:resolve>` looked like:

```
<ivy:resolve
    inline="true"
    organisation="${my.org}"
    module="${my.module}"
    revision="${my.rev}"
    conf="master"
    resolveId="test.me"/>
```

Then, you'd call it via:

```
$ ant -Dmy.org=commmons-logging \
    -Dmy.module="commons-logging" \
    -Drev="latest.release" resolve.me
```

Still interested in doing this?

Comment: I was kind of hoping this functionality was built in. Seems kind of crazy that the only way to determine what a symbolic name means is to actually download the specified object. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ivy task available that can create properties based on resolved artifact attributes:

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:artifactproperty name="[artifact].version" value="[revision]">
            <dependency org="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" rev="latest.integration"/>
        </ivy:artifactproperty>

        <echo message="Commons logging latest  = ${commons-logging.version}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

No convenient way to do this from the command-line. Hope this helps.

Notes:

- Version 2.3 of ivy supports nested dependency tags in [post resolve tasks](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/postresolvetask.html).